# Probability of visiting each cell of an $N\times M$ grid

Tags: probability

Consider an N by M grid. Rows are numbered $1$ to N, from top to bottom. Columns are numbered $1$ to M, from left to right.

We are initially at cell $(1, 1)$ and want to go to cell (N, M). From any cell we can move to the cell below it or to the cell right to it. We should never go out of the grid. At any point consider all the possibilities of movement with equal probability.

Let (i,j) be a cell of a grid. what is the probability of visiting (i,j) in our path from $(1,1)$ to (N,M)?

Comment: Do you have any thoughts about how to approach this? What kind of formulas would you find suitable to apply to such a word problem?

Comment: The probability of visiting (1,1) is of course $1$, so we can conclude the probability of visiting (1,2) and (2,1) would be both $0.5$. 
I guessed maybe probability of each cell is obtained by adding probability of the adjacent cells on the left and the top $\times 0.5$. but it is wrong since the probability of (N,M) cell is 1.

Comment: Oh, I got my mistake. problem solved :] .